# error cuando corro webpack con react js

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

Hola es mi primera vez utilizando Webpack y React. El `webpack.config.js` lo tengo en el directorio principal del proyecto.

**Código**

```
let webpack = require('webpack')
let path = require('path')

module.exports = {

    entry:{
        app: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'dist/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'dist/bundle.map'
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Log**

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe', 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js', 1 verbose cli
>   'run', 1 verbose cli   'webpack' ] 2 info using npm@6.4.1 3 info using
>   node@v10.15.0 4 verbose stack Error: missing script: webpack 4 verbose
>   stack     at run (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19) 4 verbose
>   stack     at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5 4 verbose stack
>   at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
>   4 verbose stack     at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:418:5
>   4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:373:45)
>   4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:416:3)
>   4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
>   4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext. (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20)
>   4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
>   4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete]
>   (fs.js:238:13) 5 verbose cwd
>   C:\Users\anapabio\Desktop\chatbotv1\chatv1 6 verbose Windows_NT
>   10.0.17134 7 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run"
>   "webpack" 8 verbose node v10.15.0 9 verbose npm  v6.4.1 10 error
>   missing script: webpack 11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

***package.js***

```
{
  "name": "chatv1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "webpack": "webpack --progress",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor, muestra también tu `package.json`. Así mismo, te recuerdo que debes dar la mayor información posible en tu pregunta para que las personas puedan entender tu problema y por consiguiente, ayudarte. Así mismo, tómate un poco de tiempo para plantear tu pregunta de manera gramaticalmente entendible.

Comment: En la última línea del log detallado de error que compartes, se aprecia este texto: `error missing script:`. ¿Has instalado webpack ya?

Comment: Hola si, ya tengo instalado el webpack, tambien lo instale como global pero me sigue apareciendo lo mismo , estoy usando vscode y windows 10, yo agrego el codigo del package.js